# Why can't we cast string to stringbuffer?

Tags: java

What is the reason behind this:

Why this is not allowed `StringBuffer sb=(String)"Java";`

and this is allowed `StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer("Java");`

Comment: Same reason `String s = (Integer)5;` isn't allowed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

String is an **immutable** class **derived only from Object**. Therefore you cannot cast it to another type

To get a `StringBuffer` from a `String` you must create a new `StringBuffer` instance with the String as an argument to the `constructor` as you have mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

Java is a strongly-typed language.

This means that everything has a type. For example, Strings and Stringbuffers.

Casts have two major purposes. The first is on primitives, which are all numbers (except boolean). This is a conversion. The second is on objects. The only purpose is to cast an object to one of its subclasses. For example.

```
Object s = "";
int len = ((String) s).length();
```

StringBuffer and String are unrelated heigherarchically even though they may have similar purposes

Answer (score 1):

Java does not support the casting of String to StringBuffer since String is an immutable object.

The Java API for [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) informs us there is a constructor available to create a StringBuffer from a String object:

```
StringBuffer(String str)
```

Comment: Also, String cannot be cast to StringBuffer because they are not related heigherarchicallly in any way. (Apart from descending from Object)

Answer (score 0):

In java object typecasting, one object reference can be type cast into another object reference. The cast can be to its own class type or to one of its classes in its sub class or super class hierarchy.
You may look at the below snippet to get some understanding of how type casting works. In the below code, class B is a subclass (child) of class A.

```
class A{
}

class B extends A{
}

A a = new A();  
B b = new B();  

A a1 = (A)b;    //this is correct
B b1 = (B)b;    //this is correct

A a2 = (B)a;    //ClassCastException
B b2 = (A)a;    //Compile error
```

You may want to look at some of these - [Conversions and Promotions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html) and [Java Cast and Conversions](http://javapapers.com/java/java-cast-and-conversions/) to get a better understanding of Java type conversion and promotion.